# Filtering the interrupt for rising edge or falling edge in linux kernel

Tags: kernel, driver, interrupt

I have registered a gpio to irq with raising edge and falling edge both.
My interrupt handler is called by the any signal disturbance on the pin.
**Further i want to filter the reason of interrupt , weather it was due to raising edge or falling edge. Is there any way to filter the reason of the interrupt?**

OR can i register two hander for same irq, one for falling edge and one for raising edge?

Answer (score 1):

This depends on the type of processor/architecture. Most of the processors have provision to read the appropriate register of corresponding pin to determine/filter whether the interrupt is due to rising edge or falling edge. Your processor data sheet shall have the specific information.